# Spring ContextLoader Error

Tags: spring, grails, jbilling

I tried to run JBilling Community Edition app. I have configured it properly (I think I do), but I have an error during the start up. All logs are below:

```
C:\dev\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java -Dgrails.home=C:\dev\grails-2.5.6 -Dtools.jar=C:\dev\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_131\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\dev\grails-2.5.6/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -javaagent:C:\dev\grails-2.5.6\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails;cacheDir=. -Dbase.dir=E:\workspace\jbilling\JBilling\jbilling-community-4.1.1 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\dev\grails-2.5.6\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.4.10.jar;C:\dev\grails-2.5.6\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.5.6.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\dev\grails-2.5.6/conf/groovy-starter.conf "run-app -plain-output"
|Loading Grails 2.5.6
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
.............Setting license in jbilling.properties from license.txt
.....Loading configuration files from classpath
Checking the connection to the DB...
Connected to the DB successfully!!!
.....................................Loading configuration files from classpath
.2017-09-12 14:12:54,101 0     INFO  [grails.plugin.webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin] (main:) Loading default config file: class DefaultWebXmlConfig
2017-09-12 14:12:54,115 14    WARN  [grails.plugin.webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin] (main:) Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig
2017-09-12 14:12:54,812 711   INFO  [grails.plugin.webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin] (main:) Loading default config file: class DefaultWebXmlConfig
2017-09-12 14:12:54,836 735   WARN  [grails.plugin.webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin] (main:) Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig

|Running Grails application
.Setting license in jbilling.properties from license.txt
.....2017-09-12 14:12:55,408 1307  INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] (main:) Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2017-09-12 14:12:55,440 1339  INFO  [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool] (main:) Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Loading configuration files from classpath
2017-09-12 14:12:56,149 2048  ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (localhost-startStop-1:) Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-09-12 14:12:56,150 2049  ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener] (localhost-startStop-1:) Error initializing the application: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Maybe somebody has a clue how to fix it? Any advices? I would appreciate that. It seems that the app is ok, but the only problem is spring in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem could be the grails version you have 'grails-2.5.6'.

The jB CE 4.x version is based on grails-2.4.3. You should use that.